# Multiple Chef Policyfiles

Tags: continuous-integration, chef-infra, continuous-delivery, chef-policyfile

I have a case where there are many Dev environments with different topologies, meaning that some node can have multiple roles and set of roles can vary from one environment to another.

Policyfile can be mapped to some particular runlist, but in my case I need to combine multiple Policyfiles on the same node.

I saw RFC about multi-policy, which probably not implemented yet https://github.com/chef-boneyard/chef-rfc/blob/master/rfc075-multi-policy.md

The question Is Policyfile fine workflow if set of roles for one node can vary? If yes, how this could be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can include other policyfiles in policyfile using `include_policy` directive.

Comment: I am curious how it works on practice. Can you please provide some examples?

Comment: You can look at the docs: https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_policyfile.html

Comment: If I could take a look, I wouldn't come here :/
I need some working examples. 
In my understanding it's easier to combine items in runlists by just settings runlist for nodes. In case of Policyfile workflow I would have to update client.rb file, which specify configuration for which Policyfile is used. 
I don't know how above would scale when you have 100+ environments and each of them have different topologies, meaning that each node can mix multiple roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the [solutions](https://docs.chef.io/policyfile/) that I found was to use `include_policy`, where you can combine multiple policyfiles together.